# Given $A \in R^{2\times 2}$, orthogonal matrix, and anti symmetric, find all $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $A \in R^{2 \times2}$, orthogonal matrix, and anti symmetric, find all $A$

Well,

- $A$ is orthogonal matrix, thus: $A^TA = I$
- $A$ is anti symmetric, thus: $A^T = -A$

In my opinion, $A$ must have $a_{12} = a_{21} = 0$ , and $a_{11} \cdot a_{22} = 1$ , and another condition is

**if** $0 < a_{11} \le 1$ **then** $-1 < a_{22} < 0$

**OR**

**if** $0 < a_{22} \le 1$ **then** $-1 < a_{11} < 0$

I know its kinda 'creepy' proof, and I'm not sure it is correct.

Because I think that because $A$ is orthogonal matrix, its columns vector must have $||a_1|| = ||a_2|| = 1$, if that is true, then $A$ can be only 2 matrices. with $a_{11} = 1, a_{22} = -1$, or vise versa.

What do you guys think? how many $A$ are there with these $2$ conditions, and what are they?

**Some more insight:** What will be $A^2$, and will $A$ be the rotation matrix? I think that in $(2x2)$ we know for sure that $det(A) = 1 \leftrightarrow $ rotation matrix, thus, can I say that? and how can I find the angles of $A$'s rotation?

Comment: For multiplication it's better to use \times than a letter x.

Comment: @ProbablyWrong Noted. edited. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{21}&a_{22}\end{pmatrix}$$
$$A^T=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{21}\\a_{12}&a_{22}\end{pmatrix}$$
From $A^T=-A$ you get $a_{12}=-a_{21}$, $a_{11}=-a_{11}$, $a_{22}=-a_{22}$. So $a_{11}=a_{22}=0$

What is left is
$$\begin{pmatrix}0&a_{12}\\-a_{12}&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&-a_{12}\\a_{12}&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a_{12}^2&0\\0&a_{12}^2\end{pmatrix}$$
so $a_{12}=\pm1$

Comment: possible angles are only when -sin(a) = sin(a) = 0, meaning when angle a = 90 or 270, right? so only two possible angles 90,270 for rotation

Comment: @Ilan You are correct

Answer (score 2):

Hint: consider the orthogonal matrix

$$
\pm
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(t) &-\sin(t) \\
\sin(t) & \cos(t)
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

When is it also skew-symmetric?